# Is this SQL query correct

Tags: mysql, database

I'm preparing for an exam in databases and I stumbled upon this question:

We have a database of a human resources company, it contains the tables:

`Applicant(a-id,a-city,a-name)`

```
Qualified(a-id,job-id)
```

There are more tables in the database but they won't be relevant for the question I am asking.

The question was:

We want to write a query that displays for each pair (job-id,a-city) the names of the people living in that city who are qualified for the job.

Does this query solve the question? Why?

```
Select qualified.job-id, applicant.a-city, applicant.a-name 
from qualified, applicant
where quailified.a-id=applicant.a-id
group by qualified.job-id, applicant.a-city
```

I personally think this query is fine. I can't find any faults with it, but lacking any actual way to check it, and also lacking experience with SQL, I would like someone to help me confirm that this is indeed okay.

Comment: Why not set up some test data and try it? That way you will get a 'feel' for the requirements and what the query actually does. That is how we do it. You have some test data> An [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would 'make it easy for us to be involved'.

Comment: boy those hyphens would drive me crazy who designed that train wreck

Comment: someone whose in the teaching profession, rather than a Database developer! @DrewPierce

Comment: those that know, do, those that don't, teach @Martin

Comment: Sadly as I wrote, I don't have a way of testing it since I do not have mysql installed and I don't know which version we are using in class.

Comment: sqlfiddle is your friend, assuming you have a browser. do you have a browser ?

Comment: Given that you have no way of checking any answers - why did you bother asking? We will help - however - you have to demonstrate that you have made some effort. Also, you need to provide enough information for us to workout what is required. It must be specific.

Comment: @RyanVincent cuz it is a homework question in sheep's clothing

Comment: Oria i will show ya something too. just having fun hang in there get a coke

Comment: I swear, people sometimes can be downright hostile. What more effort do you want? I think it's correct. I think it will indeed display the list of all the jobs, and all the people in each city that qualify for that job.

Comment: what was hostile. i missed it :). I have spent days at times (off and on) assisting people on 1 question

Comment: and i was going to even show you how to join a table with modern explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to SELECT every value you want to return *or compare*, so you need to also select `applicant.a-id`

```
 Select qualified.job-id, applicant.a-id, applicant.a-city, applicant.a-name 
from qualified, applicant
where quailified.a-id=applicant.a-id
group by qualified.job-id, applicant.a-city
```

I'm really not happy with the GROUP BY for these, the output will be initially grouped into the different job id's and then each of those job id's will be grouped by city,

I also feel the question is not perfectly worded, in terms of what actual output is required but assuming that the user can select the city and the job, to list the people then the GROUP BYs are in fact SELECTers:

```
   Select qualified.job-id, applicant.a-id, applicant.a-city, applicant.a-name 
    from qualified, applicant
    where quailified.a-id=applicant.a-id
    AND qualified.job-id = ? AND applicant.a-city = ? ORDER BY  applicant.a-name
```

(I am well aware this does not use the preferred JOIN syntax, but I don't think the OP needs it in this case re: comments above).